# Why are my html elements duplicating and overlapping when using media queries?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make a responsive landing page. I styled a mobile version first which seemed to work fine, but when I try to use a media query for the desktop version the elements of the html seems to duplicate and overlap. This is my first web developer project I am attemping form a site called frontend metor, so please bear with me.

```
My Html:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

    <title>Frontend Mentor | Huddle landing page with single introductory section</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/projects/fontawesome-free-5.12.0-web/css/all.css">

    <!-- Feel free to remove these styles or customise in your own stylesheet  -->
      <style>
        .attribution { font-size: 11px; text-align: center; }
      </style>
      <style>
      .attribution a { color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%); }
    </style>
  </head>
    <body>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <header>
          <img src="images\logo.svg" alt="huddle-logo">
        </header>

        <main>
          <div class="container">
            <img src="images\illustration-mockups.svg" alt="illustration-mockup">
            <h1>Build The Community <br> Your Fans Will Love</h1>
            <p>Huddle re-imagines the way we build <br> communities.You have a voice, but so <br> does your audience. Create connections <br> with your users as you engage in genuine discussion. </p>
            <button type="button" name="button">Register</button>
          </div>
        </main>

        <footer>
          <div class="font">
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class= "fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
          </div>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>

My CSS:

    html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: block;
  background: url(images/bg-mobile.svg) no-repeat top;
  background-size: contain;
  background-color: hsl(257, 40%, 49%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
}

header img {
  width: 130px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.container {
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: center;
}

main img {
  margin-top: 58px;
  width: 100%;
  }

h1, p {
  text-align: center;
}

 h1 {
   font-family: Poppins;
   margin-top: 60px;
   font-weight: 700;
   font-size: 22px;
   line-height: normal;
   color: #ffffff;
 }

  p {
   margin-top: 20px;
   font-family: 'Open Sans';
   font-weight: 400px;
   font-size: 16px;
   line-height: normal;
   color: #f2f2f2;
 }

 button {
   margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
   padding: 10px 70px;
   border-radius: 25px;
   color: hsl(257, 40%, 49%);
   background-color: #ffffff;
 }

  footer {
    align-self: center;
  }

  .font {
   padding: 50px 0 20px 0;
 }

  .fa-facebook-f, .fa-twitter, .fa-instagram{
    color: white;
    width: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 8px 12px;
 }

 @media only screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
   body {
     background: url(design/desktop-design.jpg) no-repeat ;
     background-size: cover;
   }

   .wrapper {
     margin: 0 0 0 20px;
     width: 100%;
   }

   header img {
     width: 130px;
     margin-top: 30px;
   }

   .container {
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: initial;
      justify-content: center;
   }

   main img {
     margin-top: initial;
     width: 50% ;}
 }
```

This is the mobile version (which came out fine)

https://github.com/Dannyblessed/Frontend-Mentor-Huddle-landing-page-with-single-introductory-section/blob/master/design/mobile-design.jpg

[This is how my desktop version appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ey17R.png)

This is how I want it to appear.

https://github.com/Dannyblessed/Frontend-Mentor-Huddle-landing-page-with-single-introductory-section/blob/master/design/desktop-design.jpg

This the code in jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/DanielEdwards45/a7vkfhdg/24/

Comment: Unable to reproduce, It will be helpful if you can reproduce this is in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Change your *min-width* to *max-width* and then hide your desktop images on a smaller screen size.

Comment: First I could see that you are using the "background" property, it is a shortcut of multiples params related to background. When you use inside your media query "background" again, background-color property returns to its initial state ( here is "white") so you need to define it again.

Comment: I would like to suggest you use the developer consoles of the browsers to play with the possibilities of styles that you want to give your website.

Comment: @ Sameer Khan. Ok just posted the jsfiddle link. But it does not appear the same way as in my browser.

Comment: @Gosi tried that and nothing changed

Comment: @DanielEdwards What is the outcome you want? In desktop version, what do you want to display?

Comment: When it goes to desktop, only your register button is out of place, is that the issue? Or is it something else?

Comment: @Gosi. ok I just adding a link to how I want the desktop version to appear(Should of added that initially sorry), but the problem is not about the position of my elements but the fact that the elements seem to double when it goes to desktop and just looks weird in general. for example there are two logos when it goes desktop.

Comment: @Gosi jsfiddle dose not seem to be presenting it the same way my browser is so refer to the link that I presented in the post to see the issue.